# How can I reference User Information off the SimpleMembership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-membership

Using EF-Code-First I want to set up a DB table that is related (1-1) to the inbuilt Simple Membership provider that comes OOTB with ASP.Net 4.0+

The UserProfile class in AccountModels.cs is a simple 2 field class:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

My class with other user info I want to keep separate has this format:

```
[Table("UserInfo")]
public class UserInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    <user info fields here...>
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

The Context is:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserInfo> UsersInfo { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserInfo>()
                    .HasRequired(u => u.UserProfile)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}
```

Now, without changing anything else, when I run the app, the models build fine, but I'm getting a error when `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);` runs (Acct Controller Line 82). `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "UserInfo_UserProfile".`

What is the (assumed) preferred method of storing user information that I want to be able to reference directly from the DB later (ie. not in blobs as per the old Profile provider)

How do I set this up using EF-CodeFirst as opposed to running everything through a repository layer? Should I just go the repository route?

I had trouble getting azureSQL to include more columns in the UserProfile table when I tested that method, so would like to keep the userInfo stuff out of UserProfile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<UserInfo>()
                    .HasRequired(u => u.UserProfile)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

Means your UserProfile class in turn requires UserInfo. Since SimpleMembership will insert into UserProfile and not UserInfo, the exception is thrown.

I don't think you need this off the top of my head since your relationship is optional - UserProfile will exist before UserInfo, as simplemembership will create it prior to you creating a UserInfo.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/257f33d2-9870-46ce-9b0b-147935162a0c